# Reading SQL Server database

Tags: c#, sql-server, database

I need to read data from a SQL Server database. Something doesn't work with syntax of the table, which has Id as a primary key plus several items.

```
SqlConnection CON = new SqlConnection("Data Source = pc\\sqlexpress; Initial Catalog = dccDB; Integrated Security = True");
string strSQL = "SELECT Id Item" + "FROM [dbo.Table]";

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(strSQL, CON);
{
    CON.Open();
    MessageBox.Show("SQL DataBase dccDB.dbo is connected");
    SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();     (ERROR !!!)

    while ( reader.Read() )
    {
       MessageBox.Show( reader["Id"].ToString(), reader["Item"].ToString());
    }

    reader.Close();
    CON.Close();
}
```

There is a error message: ex.Message

> Wrong syntax close to 'dbo.Table'.

Many thanks for your ideas.

Comment: "SELECT Id Item" => "SELECT Id,Item " and [dbo.Table] => [dbo].[Table]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're missing a space in your SQL and using the brackets incorrectly. Columns need to be separated by commas. The line should be:

```
string strSQL = "SELECT Id, Item FROM [dbo].[Table]";
```

Answer (score 2):

Have a space after Item in ur query, and separate dbo.table to [dbo].[table] like:

```
string strSQL = "SELECT Id, Item " + "FROM [dbo].[Table]";
```

Comment: Need a comma between Id & Item too, otherwise it's just returning Id column aliased as 'Item'

Comment: Cool, sorry I should have suggested it as an edit, still learning how to SO :)

Comment: Eray, I changed the line as recommended including comma and separating dbo and table. Now it gives an error "Wrong syntax close to '.' ???

Answer (score 1):

There is no space between Item and From, replace your strSql line with following:

```
string strSQL = "SELECT Id Item " + "FROM [dbo.Table]";
```